# Can't get Python class code to work

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. Anyway, I was trying to make a 21 questions game, but my code won't work.

The error is: `Name 'plux' is not defined.`

Here is the code:

```
from random import randint


class Game(object):
    num = randint(1, 3)
    def plux(x):
        x += 1
        return x
    def minu(x):
        x -= 1
    def iff(i):
        apple = 0
        num = randint(1, 3)
        if num == 1:
            x = input('Can you eat it? ').lower()
            if x == "yes" or "yeah":
                print("test num 1")
                apple = plux(apple)

        elif num == 2:
            print('test num 2')
        elif num == 3:
            print("test num 3")
a = Game()
print(a.iff())
```

Comment: Each function should have an additional `self` argument at the beginning, and every call to functions should have `self.` added before.  That is because they are actually methods of the class, not global functions.

Comment: @zondo using __init__()? Do you think you could give an example?

Comment: from @zondo's comment your code should look like this http://pastebin.com/fPb8Djgj

Comment: @danidee oh thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function `plux` in the line `apple = plux(apple)`, add a `self.` in front of the function call. In Python, `self.` is used as a reference to the object itself that is used within the class scope (any place inside of the `Game` class). In every function of a class, `self` has to be the first parameter (this is something I don't know why we must do, I'm sure there is a reason for it, but just follow this convention carefully).

Answer (score 0):

The class should look like this (missing self):

```
from random import randint

class Game(object):

        def __init__(self):
            self.num = randint(1, 3)
            self.x=0

        def plux(self):
            self.x += 1

        def minu(self):
            self.x -= 1

        def iff(self):
            apple = 0
            self.num = randint(1, 3)

            if self.num == 1:

                x = raw_input('Can you eat it? ').lower()

                if x == "yes" or "yeah":
                    print("test num 1")
                    apple = self.plux()

            elif self.num == 2:
                print('test num 2')

            elif self.num == 3:
                print("test num 3")

a = Game()
a.iff()
```